# Logger arguments became an array object

Tags: java, logback

I'm having a problem with passing var args to Logger.

My String message pass to Logger is something like:

```
String message = "[{}] [{}] - This is a message from {} to {}"
```

and I pass arguments to Logger:

```
Logger.info(message, hostAddress, username, earth, mar);
```

And the output of above is: `[0.0.0.1] [admin] - This is a message from Earth to Mar`

But I don't want to pass the `hostAddress` and `username` every time to Logger, so my idea is shorten it, automatically pass `hostAddress` and `username`:

```
public void logMessage(String message, Object... args) {
     Logger.info(message, getHostAddress(), getUsername(), args);
}
```

used by:

```
logMessage(message, earth, mar);
```

But the output will be: `[0.0.0.1] [admin] - This is a message from [Earth,Mar] to`

Not as my expect was:  `[0.0.0.1] [admin] - This is a message from Earth to Mar`

Var args became an array object,

How can I solve the problem above?

Thanks!

Comment: Your observation is absolutely correct: `Object... args` is the same as `Object[] args`

Comment: But is there any idea to make it output like `[0.0.0.1] [admin] - This is a message from Earth to Mar` on my logMessage ?

Comment: If this should be an application wide configuration, you can look into *Mapped Diagnostic Context*. Then you add the parameters to the context and it will be inserted automatically without having to create a wrapper. Example: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Comment: Thank you @Matt, I will take a look at this

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by passing the `new Object[] {arg, arg}` to logMessage and its output as I expected.

Kinda strange that if I pass var args, Logger will send all array's element to the first `{}`, not distribute to all `{}`

Comment: I don't see how `new Object[] {arg, arg}` would solve your problem described in the question. There must be something else that made it work now.